# Falha ao converter o nvarchar valor 'Array' para o tipo de dados int

Tags: php, pdo, mvc, int

Olá. Estou com alguns problemas para inserir valores numa tabela.

Explicando melhor, eu pego o AID gerado em Account e preciso inseri-lo em Login. Obtive sucesso em consultar o AID gerado em Account mas tenho problemas ao inseri-lo, o erro é o seguinte:

Notice: Array to string conversion & Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falha ao converter o nvarchar valor 'Array' para o tipo de dados int.

A palavra array é para ser o numero do AID gerado, mas no erro ele manda com a palavra Array, mas no meu var_dump ($result) exibe o número, isso me confunde um pouco.

Segue o código:

```
    public function save(){
    $query = "insert into Account(UserID, UGradeID, PGradeID, RegDate, Name, Email)values(:userid, 0, 0, GETDATE(), :name, :email)";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $this->__get('userid'));
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $this->__get('name'));
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $this->__get('email'));
    //$stmt->bindValue(':password', $this->__get('password'));
    $stmt->execute();

    $sql = "SELECT AID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE UserID = :userid";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':userid', $this->__get('userid'));
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result['AID'];
    //$result->result;

    print_r($result);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO LOGIN(UserID, AID, Password) VALUES (:userid, :result, :password)";
    $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare($insert);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':userid', $this->__get('userid'));
    $stmt2->bindParam(':result', $result);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':password', $this->__get('password'));
    $stmt2->execute();

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas tenta adicionar o tipo
Segue exemplo.

Adicionando individual.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':userid', $this->__get('userid'),PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Montando tudo dinamicamente.

```
foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
    if (is_int($value))
        $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    elseif (is_bool($value))
        $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    elseif (is_null($value))
        $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
    elseif (is_string($value))
        $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    else
        $param = false;

    if ($param) $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value, $param);
}
```

Comment: Agradeço sua disposição em me ajudar, mas descobri o problema. Era a forma em que eu acessava a query do result que estava errada, era necessário atribuir uma outra variavel e fazer a pesquisa pelo AID. Neste caso do post principal, ele estava recuperando toda query, não somente o AID.